# MSI Unistall: How to force uninstall UI sequence

Tags: wix, windows-installer

When uninstalling an application by double clicking the MSI that I have created via WIX, I get the "Change, Repair, Remove" dialog as I have designed.  But, when uninstalling via Add/Remove programs OR from the command line via `msiexec /x` I do not.   All I get is "Are you sure you want to uninstall this program?"

I would like to force the user to always be prompted with the "Change, Repair, Remove" dialog when uninstalling.  The reason is I have some custom UIs invoked upon Removal.  Another alternative is to always force the user through the Removal UI sequence I have designed.

Any hints on how to do this with WiX?

Answer (score 2):

If you want show Dialog in InstallUISequence table when uninstall, try it: 

**STEP 1**: Condition to show Dialog in UISequence table is REMOVE = "ALL"

**STEP 2**: "msiexec.exe /x {ProductCode} /qf"

qf: Full UI

Good Luck!

Comment: Is there any way to use this in property instead of passing explicitly /qf option?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to set [**ARPNOREMOVE property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367591(v=vs.85).aspx) to **1**.

This way the user can only select Change or Modify and full UI is used
. Overriding the install button is somewhat complicated and usually it's not worth it.

Comment: After setting that property, when double clicking the App from the Add/Remove programs, I go straight into Repair mode with NO UI.  What do I need to do to get the UI to fire up?  Next question is once I get the UI to fire up, what do I need to do to create a remove option?

Comment: Once you have the UI shown you could set the property Remove="All" to uninstall your product.

Comment: You can also have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269289/wix-msi-package-uninstallation

Comment: Double clicking the Add Remove Programs entry performs the first available operation, which is usually Uninstall or Repair. But the user can click the Change (Vista) or Modify (XP) button to launch the MSI in maintenance mode, just like launching your installer again. If you want to also hide the Repair button and always use Modify button, set both ARPNOREPAIR and ARPNOREMOVE to 1. This way double-clicking the entry will launch your MSI in maintenance mode with full UI.

Comment: Settting RPNOREPAIR and ARPNOREMOVE to 1 causes doubling clicking from the Add Remove Programs to do nothing.  Makes sense really.

Answer (score 1):

If you just use an MSI, you unfortunately can't control this. Generally to force an uninstall UI sequence you will need to implement a bootstrapper and have that call your MSI with the desired UILevel rather than letting ARP call your MSI directly.

Comment: I suspect this is the direction to head.  Do you know of any good links describing how to do this?

Comment: btw, I know how to bootstrap other installers (i.e. SQL Express, .NET, etc).  Just curious how to bootstrap my own msi.

Comment: You can take a look at the rough implementation using Burn that the WiX team have in place for WiX 3.6. Also take a look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233642/how-do-you-make-a-really-nice-installer-like-visual-studios